# PHP server veriable PHP_AUTH_USER was working, now same value get in HTTP_PHP_AUTH_USER variable of server in php

Tags: php, header

from the Google merchant product feed, I was getting username by `"PHP_AUTH_USER"`. but now I am getting same value by `"HTTP_PHP_AUTH_USER"` variable. same thing happened with `"PHP_AUTH_PW"` and `"HTTP_PHP_AUTH_PW"`. So my question is why variable name get changed? what is reason for this ?

Comment: I am sorry, I was checking by Post man(google Crom's plugin), but actually , I am not getting either PHP_AUTH_USER or HTTP_PHP_AUTH_USER in google feed's request

Comment: any one has a idea how to get Username password from the Google Product feed, to validate the Request ?